# can we identify in the mob app what are the database is using?

Tags: android, sqlite

I dont know how to ask this question, I know sqlite exists on every android system and I understand how to work with sqlite database

My question , can I know what are the database and tables any `mobile application` is using in my sqlite android. lets say facebook app using sqlite in my android , can I know what are the tables is using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for that you have to [root](http://www.xda-developers.com/root/) your android device then you will be able to fetch all the applications data in your phone. all the applications are located under `/data/data/` directory